# Auto reload a piece of code in PHP using Ajax maybe?

Tags: php, ajax

Hello I need the value of nextid to be reloaded without refreshing the whole page. How can I do this? Thanks!

```
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT MAX(ID) FROM $wpdb->posts";
$currid = $wpdb->get_var($query);
$nextid = $currid+1;
```

Comment: Can you give more info on what you're trying to do?  You may be able to use the next id without having to reload anything.

Comment: @kevinmajor1 Sure, I use Wordpress and a plugin that allow you to post from a form. This plugin allow you to create many forms. So, because of some modification i made to the core for my form number 1, i need to have the next of the latest post id for form 2 to be posted correctly. Did it and it is working. The value is added to a textbox name permalink. However, as I am writing there may be a new post. So my post's id will match the one that it was just posted. That's why :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and you would use ajax.. the life cycle would go something like this:

1. Browser requests page
2. PHP runs and returns html/javascript/css/etc.
3. javascript runs in browser, using ajax calling a php script on the server
4. php script returns the results as text or html or json or some other format
5. javascript takes the results, clears out the old information on the page and puts in the new information
6. goto 3

There are a ton of javascript libraries out there to help with that part of things. I have used jQuery and highly recommend it.

**Update**: A simple ajax example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'page.php',
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, data) {
            // error
            alert(jqXHR.responseText);
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // result
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks. I updated my post. I used this but I can't use it properly because the variable is in a textbox, not in a div...

Comment: The load function is a very very high level and spesifically purposed ajax. I would use the ajax method. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  load the information and have your javascript put it where you need it.

Comment: Because I am new to Ajax/jQuery can you find me a tutorial/example based on my needs? Or give me some keywords to do it myself. All my results give me the one that have to do with div.

Comment: Mikey - I added a very simple example of the ajax method. I fetched the result of page.php and alert it, if there is an error, alert it. No what you do with the data returned is up to you. you can add it to a text box with $('#IdOfTextbox').val(data); or put it in a div $('#IdOfDiv').html(data); or anything else you want to with it.